# How do I find out references to myObject?

Tags: smalltalk, visual-age

When searching down a memory leak (sticky object) in smalltalk, I would like to get the references to an instance of my objects (retreived by doing a `Foo allInstances` ).

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Age Smalltalk:

```
myObject allReferences
```

Comment: In Pharo `myObject pointersTo`. This question is VA-specific, but maybe this information will be useful to someone else

Comment: @Uko that's [tag:Pharo] 1.3+ specific. Earlier versions used `PointerFinder pointersTo: myObject`. [tag:Squeak] 4.4 uses `myObject chasePointers`